# Decorator pattern in smalltalk

Tags: decorator, smalltalk, squeak

I have unavailingly been searching for a proper implementation of the decorator pattern in smalltalk. Could someone please provide me with a reference?

Edit: I am building a game with a player and a simple collision object. Instead of subclassing, I want to use decorators to construct slightly different versions of the same collision object at runtime (e.g. one that explodes, one that moves, one that does both, etc.).

Comment: please, describe better how are you planning to use a decorator.

Comment: i edited my post to add an explanation

Comment: Are you sure you want a decorator and not a strategy?

Comment: @Tobias By encapsulating a certain behaviour, strategy pattern would allow me to completely switch out the strategy. However, I only want to extend the behaviour, not change it completely. Actually I need something like an array of strategies to be executed. Would this still be strategy pattern?

Comment: @Thyrel The seminal book on Smalltalk patterns implementation is *"The Design Patterns Smalltalk Companion" by Sherman R. Alpert, Kyle Brown and Bobby Woolf, Addison Wesley (1998)*. It has a chapter on the decorator pattern..

Comment: @Thyrel this sounds more like a chain-of-responsibility to me, decorators might fit, however. The Gang-Of-Four book is quite elaborate on both patterns. You should tailor them to your use case, however. (Also, consider MartinW's recommendation)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Seaside, and `WADecoration`. While an excellent reference, it might not be very easy to understand, as Seaside uses a few more patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decorator pattern to model a list of multiple behaviours by chaining multiple decorations together ahead of the leaf instance.

You can extract a more general decorator method like this:

```
decorated
    self decoration.
    forward decorated.
```

The class needs an instance method like:

```
initialise: forwarded
    forward:=forwarded.
```